# Compressing a folder into another directory using shell script returned an error

Tags: linux, shell

I am using Linux Enterprise  Redhat release 5

I need to compress a folder through shell script then to be run every Thu 
through cronjob but I got an error.  Below are the details regarding to my 
problem:

What I aim by doing this command to be run through shell script:
compressing a folder  **/Stage/prodDB11gr2/    into another location /Stage/apps_backup/oracle_home_backup**

So, what I did to implement so:

`cd /Stage
tar -cf /Stage/apps_backup/oracleDB_home_backup/prodDB11gr2.zip  prodDB11gr2/`

What error I got:

tar: /Stage/apps_backup/oracleDB_home_backup/prodDB11gr2.zip: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

What is the owner,permission set and the file name that has that tar command to be executed through:
$HOME/oracle_DB_home_backup.sh

**-rwxr-xr-- 1 oracle oracle 425 Aug  5 17:21 oracle_DB_home_backup.sh**

Through which user I am executing that job:
the owner: oracle

How the crontab row looks like regarding to that job:

**25 17 * * 5 /home/oracle/oracle_DB_home_backup.sh**

The error says "Cannot open: No such file or directory"

What I thought of  when I read that message is (permission  and the path of these directories)
So, I checked these files:

1. The target directory I want to compress:

**drwxrwxr-x 3 oracle oracle  4096 Jan 19  2015 prodDB11gr2**

2. The location of the new directory I am going to compress the  file  into:

**drwxrwxr-x 2 oracle oracle 4096 Aug  3 10:20 oracle_home_backup**

How my script looks like:

`## taking weekly ORACLE_HOME backup
cd /Stage
tar -cf /Stage/apps_backup/oracleDB_home_backup/prodDB11gr2.zip  prodDB11gr2/`

I checked again whether that the target directory is accessible and really exists:

`$ pwd
/Stage/apps_backup/oracle_home_backup`

I have no idea what I am missing here...Kindly, help!

Comment: For a good example of what you are trying to do: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-compress-a-whole-linux-or-unix-directory/  You are missing the "z" flag to create the zip. You don't need the v flag if it is running in a cron job but it is good for visually inspecting what is going on while you test.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My mistake was with the path of of the target directory.  Instead of oracle_home_backup, I wrote oracleDB_home_backup.  That is why it was returning inaccessible related error when running that command. It worked without adding z flag.